# How do a Chrome Extension background.html access the current window (user's content window)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

**chrome.windows.getCurrent** only gets me the background.html itself. What I really want is the content window that the user is browsing.

Any tips for this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current window is the window that contains the code that is currently executing. It's important to realize that this can be different from the topmost or focused window.
For example, say an extension creates a few tabs or windows from a single HTML file, and that the HTML file contains a call to chrome.tabs.getSelected. The current window is the window that contains the page that made the call, no matter what the topmost window is.

If you want to get content window what user is browsing you can use following code:

***popup.js***

```
chrome.windows.getAll({"populate":true},function (windows){
    for(i=0;i<windows.length ;i++){
        if(windows[i].focused){
            for(j=0;j<windows[i].tabs.length;j++){
                if(windows[i].tabs[j].selected && windows[i].tabs[j].active && windows[i].tabs[j].highlighted ){
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(windows[i].tabs[j]));
                }
            }
        }   
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get the native window object? I want to call a "getSelection()"

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo: If you are looking at contents of what a tab contains, you can get it with script injection.

Comment: Thanks, actually I hope to get the window object in my background.html without adding content script (due to some security limits)

Comment: Having window object in background.html is not feasible in chrome extensions, you have to go for content scripts

Comment: @Sudarshan `chrome.tabs.query({active:true,highlighted:true,lastFocusedWindow:true}, function (tab){console.debug(tab);})` Same as your code, minus the selected that doesnt exist ;)  Liking your answers by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use chrome.windows.getLastFocused()?